# Getting started with vBulletin development

Tags: php, documentation, plugins, vbulletin

I was asked if I could program something for vBulletin. As I never programmed something for vBulletin I started to search for documentation and tutorials. Unfortunately I wasn't very lucky.

The most promising thing I found was [this](http://members.vbulletin.com/api/), but it looks like it was autogenerated and isn't very helpful for beginners. After some more searching I found a collection of tutorials in the vBulletin forums ([3.5/3.6 Tutorial index](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=99570)), but the forum hides all code from non-members and I don't think I get an account without buying a vBulletin licence.

Is there a way to find if what I want to do is possible and more or less easy to integrate into vBulletin, without buying a licence?

Comment: You can register for the vBulletin forums without a license: http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/register.php

Comment: The problem is that the message "You are currently showing up as unlicensed" appears at the top of every page and the code blocks state "Suspended or Unlicensed Members Cannot View Code.".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964). Open source licensing questions can be asked on [OpenSource.SE]. Legal questions may be asked on [Law.SE].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vBulletin is particularly difficult to code for without a copy of their source. There isn't enough information in the documentation to allow you to code with confidence. More importantly, you have no way of testing your code.

I don't know about the newer licenses, but I think some of the older ones are transferable. You might be able to pick up a second-hand license for a reasonable price if a new license is outside your budget. If you go down this route, be careful of code changes between vB 3.7, 3.8 and 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Budget is not my problem, it's more that I can't just buy a licence of something I'm not going to use afterwards :). I'll look around for a second hand one.

Comment: If budget isn't a problem, check if the new licenses are transferable. If so, perhaps buying one and re-selling it (if necessary) would be the smartest option?